# Kafka subscriber vs consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I've just started learning about Kafka and on a high level, I'm not fully understanding the difference between a subscriber and a consumer. They seem very similar to me, what is the distinct functionality of each.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're the same thing, just different name. Consumer is the Kafka terminology, but in general messaging terms a Consumer is a subscriber to a topic.